# How to Clear the PHP CLI Screen in Windows: A Simple Method Similar to 'cls' Command

Tags: php, windows

When PHP script run from command line (windows) , how can clear the console screen from script .

for example :

```
while(true){
    // sleep for 10 seconds , then clear the console
    sleep(10);

    // below command execute to clear the console windows
    **COMMAND**
}
```

Comment: `system('cls');` does not work for me in Win7

Comment: This is marked as a duplicate of a question that is not the same.  The linked question asks how to clear a line and this question asks how to clear the screen.  Those are NOT the same thing.

Comment: Agreed this should not have been closed, and I have voted to reopen.

Comment: `popen('cls', 'w');` is the way to do it. works in win10.

Comment: Confirmed, `pclose(popen('cls','w'));`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you did not have any luck with the solutions above, consider the following

```
echo chr(27).chr(91).'H'.chr(27).chr(91).'J';   //^[H^[J
```

Hope it will help.

Source : http://pank.org/blog/2011/02/php-clear-terminal-screen.html

Comment: This seems way more performant than `system('clear')`. Is it also cross-platform? What are the drawbacks?

Comment: doesnt work on windows

Comment: Worked on Windows 10... I'm guessing this will work ever since the cmd prompt start supporting ansi escape chars.

Comment: Also, by the way, this can be shortened to: `echo "\e[H\e[J";` (in plain PHP)

Comment: @StevenMartin really? works fine for me on Windows 7 x64 SP1

Comment: This does not work for me on Win7 Home 64bit

Comment: confirmed still working windows 10

Comment: I was surprised to see that this also works remotely with curl even...

Comment: June 2023 -- works on windows 10 for me, this is cool!

Answer (score 21):

For Windows users :

```
system('cls');
```

For Linux users :

```
system('clear');
```

Comment: Seems, that `clear` works only [in Powershell](http://superuser.com/questions/585238/clear-windows-command-prompt-screen-using-keyboard-shortcuts#comment1122664_585241). When executing your PHP script in pure Windows command-line, you should still use `cls`.

Comment: system("cls") will put a chr(12) on your screen ("form feed" character) but won't clear it.

Comment: Does not work on windows.

Comment: why is this an accepted answer, it does not work on Windows anymore?!

Comment: So there's no solution for Windows users? 
system('cls') will not work, why this answer is marked as accepted?

Comment: system("cls"); does not work for me on Windows 7 x64 SP1

Answer (score 5):

Found a solution, that works in both `cmd` and GitBash. However, this is the ugliest implementation of clearing console-screen I can think of. Pity, that there isn't any working alternative.

The "magic" is to... poke console with fifty new-lines, like that:

```
public function clearStdin()
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) echo "\r\n";
}
```

This is a modified (fixed?) version of [this non-working (for me) post from 2006](http://www.jimmyr.com/blog/Clear_Screen_in_PHP_195_2006.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using:

```
ncurses_clear();
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ncurses-clear.php

**Edit: As trejder says this solution is only for supported platforms, it seems windows is not one of them.**

Comment: OP asks for a **Windows**-based soluton! `ncurses` library [is **NOT** available](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.ncurses.php) for Windows platform in PHP.