# How to action a command from a PHP script in the current CLI context?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Suppose I have a PHP script that prints time.

```
echo time() . "\r\n";
```

Executing this script several times in CLI will look like this:

```
curiosity:bin gajus$ php -r 'echo time() . "\r\n";'
1434453316
curiosity:bin gajus$ php -r 'echo time() . "\r\n";'
1434453318
curiosity:bin gajus$ php -r 'echo time() . "\r\n";'
1434453319
curiosity:bin gajus$
```

I want my PHP script to print [`printf '\e\]50;ClearScrollback\a'`](https://superuser.com/a/726295/69534) sequence that would clear iTerm2 scrollback. I have tried variations of `php -r 'echo "\e\]50;ClearScrollback\a" .time() . "\r\n";'` but that just spits the string to the CLI output:

```
curiosity:bin gajus$ php -r 'echo "\e\]50;ClearScrollback\a" .time() . "\r\n";'
]50;ClearScrollback\a1434453543
curiosity:bin gajus$
```

Is there a way to trigger CLI `ClearScrollback` from within PHP script?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327544/how-can-clear-screen-in-php-cli-like-cls-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The escape code `^[]50;ClearScrollback^G` itself is described in [Proprietary Escape Codes](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-escape-codes.html) iTerm2 documentation.

> A quick comment on notation: in this document, ^[ means "Escape" (hex code 0x1b) and ^G means "bel" (hex code 0x07).

You can use [PHP chr()](http://php.net/chr) function, e.g.

```
php -r 'echo chr(27) . "]50;ClearScrollback" . chr(7);'
```

The `chr` function returns a specific ascii character. In this example I am using [ASCII control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart) "escape" (27) and "bell" (7). It is a cross-platform safe method to describe ascii control characters.

Comment: This prints the output, as it should, but does not trigger the command in CLI. https://gist.github.com/gajus/427c1314e58c326e90d7

Comment: Your suggestion using `exec` executes an external program, as opposed to triggering a change in the current CLI session.

Comment: Ok, check the modified answer

Comment: @Samule This works. Please, can you explain why does it work? Does a terminal such as iTerm interpret literally all of the program output and suppose it contains is an escape code, it will execute it?

Comment: I have edited your answer to include explanation as I understand it. I trust that you will correct it if I am wrong about anything.

Comment: For my own future references (and possibly useful to others too), a simple PHP function to detect the terminal type and action the corresponding equivalent of clear scrollback. https://gist.github.com/gajus/2f2d7cb9c674a8b8e86c