# How to update (clear previous value) screen with PHP?

Tags: php, loops

I echo a variable to the screen in a `while` loop. The variable increments by 1 up to 10.

So I show it on screen `echo $a;`

But I want to clear the screen from the previous value before it echoes the new one.

In Pascal for example it was `ClrScr;`.

I looked a bit for the code to clear screen but I don't think what I found is exactly what I wanted, nor did I understood it :P

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327544/how-can-clear-screen-in-php-cli-like-cls-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

```
echo $a;
```

You can add

```
echo exec('clear');
```