# PHP CLI :: Clear Screen

Tags: php, windows, command-line-interface

Too bad to be true... but reality was surprising enough after googling such a simple topic without any proper solution...

Admins please don't mark it as a double because none of the answers here :
[How can clear screen in php cli (like cls command)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327544/how-can-clear-screen-in-php-cli-like-cls-command) was working under Windows platform.

I tried :

```
system('cls');
```

I tried :

```
system('clear'); //Might work under Linux
```

I tried :

```
echo chr(27).chr(91).'H'.chr(27).chr(91).'J';
```

I tried :

```
ncurses_clear();
```

I tried :

```
passthru('clear');
```

I tried :

```
passthru('cls');
```

None of them was working for me (...as you  might guess)

I need the cursor to come back to 0,0 position so please don't post any loop of blank strings or "\r\n" to the screen.

Comment: There cannot be a cross platform way to do this, since there is no cross platform way to clear the screen in different environments you execute some php command in.

Comment: I know I post everything so if someone else will google it he might find a solution under my question :D

Comment: I wrote "there cannot be" - how do you expect anyone to still offer a solution? You have to write a wrapper that detects the environment or use some more intelligent approach, _changing_ the environment, like for example the `screen` utility.

Comment: Did you check this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320081/clear-php-cli-output